# Python Multiprocessing Pool : kill processes after any k jobs are done

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool, terminate

I have a function where I call `n` processes using Pool.starmap(). I want to terminate all the processes after any `k` out of `n` are completed. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done more easily with either `Pool.imap_unordered` or with `concurrent.futures.as_completed` on a `list` of submitted tasks. In either case, the solution is the same; iterate the resulting iterator `k` times (e.g. with `itertools.slice`), then terminate the `Pool` (in the `Executor` case, call `shutdown(cancel_futures=True)`, or make sure you cancel all the outstanding tasks manually). For example, instead of:

```
with Pool() as pool:
    results = pool.starmap(func, makes_tuples())
```

which collects all the results as a single operation and removes your ability to stop processing midstream, you do:

```
from itertools import islice

# Defined at global scope as simple wrapper to allow non-starmap functions to
# be used with iterators of argument tuples
def starcall_func(args):
    return func(*args)

...

with Pool() as pool:
     results = list(islice(pool.imap_unordered(starcall_func, makes_tuples()), k))

# When with exits, pool is terminated automatically, and only k results were collected
```

Comment: Did you just invent the *cancel_futures* keyword parameter to the `shutdown` method? I don't believe that `concurrent.futures.Executor` provides any method of terminating an already started task. Calling `cancel` on a `Future` instance that hasn't started *will* prevent it from starting, but that isn't quite the same thing. I would stick with calling `terminate` on a `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` instance.

Comment: @Booboo: `cancel_futures` was introduced in 3.9, so yeah, it's pretty new and you couldn't use it before (of course, in this case, you have a collection of all the futures, so you can cancel them all yourself fairly easily). And yeah, it won't stop a task in the middle, so the closest you could get would be `cancel_futures=True` plus `wait=False` which cancels what it can and doesn't make you block on what's currently running; it lets them finish then closes up shop. `terminate` (or equivalently, exiting a `with` block controlling a `Pool`) is the most aggressive solution.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I had no idea.